# jQuery Image loading

Tags: jquery, loading

```
$('.photoRow a[id^=clickPhoto]').click(function()
    {
        $('#layerBg').show();
        $(this).show();
        var id = parseInt($(this).attr('id').substr(10));

        var img = new Image();
        img.src = '/p/' + id + '.jpg';

        $('.photoWindow').fadeIn().html(img);        
        var pWidth = $(window).width();
        var pTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var eWidth = $('.photoWindow').width();
        alert(eWidth);
        $('.photoWindow').css('top', pTop + 10 + 'px');
        $('.photoWindow').css('left', parseInt((pWidth / 2) - (eWidth / 2)) + 'px');
        $('.photoWindow').show();
    });
```

eWidth = 600 (default in css);
I need to make eWidth considered only after the image (img) loaded into the class .photoWindow

If my picrute in the cache that eWidth is correct.

If my picture has a width of 912, then the value eWidth should be 912, but not 600..

I hope you understand me.. Sorry for bad english!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question, you want to evaluate eWidth only after the image is loaded.
First where is your image loaded and what is the element using the class `photoWindow`?

Supposing it's on an `img` element. If that's so you could use :

```
$('.photoWindow').load(function() {
        eWidth = $('.photoWindow').width();
        $('.photoWindow').css('top', pTop + 10 + 'px');
        $('.photoWindow').css('left', parseInt((pWidth / 2) - (eWidth / 2)) + 'px');
        $('.photoWindow').show();
});
```

So whenever the `<img>` element is loaded you'll calculate and place the image wherever you want.

Comment: $('.photoWindow img').load(... THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it looks as if you're attempting to pull the eWidth from the width of the photoWindow element. Why not grab it from the image itself?

```
eWidth = $('.photoWindow img').width();
```

I may also be missing something, but I'm unclear as to why you're performing a fadeIn() and a show() on the photoWindow - fadeIn() will display the element once it's completed firing.

You may also be able to refactor that final block of code operating on the photoWindow like this:

```
$('.photoWindow').css({
  top: pTop + 10 + 'px',
  left: parseInt((pWidth / 2) - (eWidth / 2)) + 'px')
});
```